# Bug in Drive API : parents.delete does not always returns http 404 when parentId is not a valid Id

Tags: google-drive-api

I've just found a weird bug in the parents.delete request in drive API.

I try to delete a non existing parent reference of a given file with these parameters :

```
fileId = validExistingFileId
parentId = nonExistingParentId
```

By non existing parent, i mean an id that produce a 404 error when requesting it using File.get

I have two different results : when nonExistingParentId is something that does not even look like an id, say 642187, i get my wanted 404. But when it is something that "looks like" a valid id, i got a 204 response, which would be the wanted response if parentId was indeed referencing a file in my drive.

I know this is not very clear, so if a Google man want to take action on this behaviour, I'll gladfully give him the specific ids I tried

**EDIT**

Maybe I need to clarify a bit.

I'd like to know if it is possible to be sure to receive an error from the API if either parentId or fileId references an unexisting resource in Google Drive, which is not the case with my curent process.

And a little thing for the downvoters here, whom I never saw answering or commenting [[image]google-drive-sdk](/questions/tagged/google-drive-sdk) questions : SO is the only access point to he Drive API support, even if i still got no answer from google concerning most of my questions. Maybe using SO as a bug tracker is not one of the best practices at Google, but who am I to change that ? So please, think twice before closing/downvoting Drive related questions.

Best Regards